# How to validate two properties which depend on each other?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, dependencies

I have view model with 2 properties: `A` and `B` and I want to validate that `A < B`.

Below is my simplified implementation where I use custom validation rule. Since each property is validated independently, it lead to an anoying issue: if entered `A` value is invalid, than it stay so even after changing `B`, since validation of `B` doesn't know anything about `A`.

This can be seen on this demo:

[image]

`A` is invalid after entering `11`, that's correct since `11 > 2`. Changing `B` to `22` doesn't re-evalute `A`, I have to edit `A` to have validation passed.

What I want? I want that after enering `22` into `B` the red border (validation error) disappears and `A = 11, B = 22` would be source values in view model.

How can I in `B` validation somehow force `A` validation after new `B` value is synchronized with source?

---

View model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _a;
    public int A
    {
        get => _a;
        set
        {
            _a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    int _b;
    public int B
    {
        get => _b;
        set
        {
            _b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

View:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{local:MyBinding A}" />
    <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{local:MyBinding B}" />
</StackPanel>
```

View code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel { A = 1, B = 2 };
}
```

Binding:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    public MyBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        ValidationRules.Add(new MyValidationRule());
    }
}
```

Validation rule:

```
public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public MyValidationRule() : base(ValidationStep.ConvertedProposedValue, false) { }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) => ValidationResult.ValidResult; // not used

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingExpressionBase owner)
    {
        var binding = owner as BindingExpression;
        var vm = binding?.DataItem as ViewModel;
        switch (binding.ResolvedSourcePropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(vm.A):
                if ((int)value >= vm.B)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "A should be smaller than B");
                break;
            case nameof(vm.B):
                if ((int)value <= vm.A)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "B should be bigger than A");
                break;
        }
        return base.Validate(value, cultureInfo, owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you also call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(B))` in the setter of a `A` (and the equivalent for the setter of `B`)?

Comment: @Dirk, this will lead to discard change: `A = 1, B = 22`. It's better than currently, but not ideal. I was hoping someone could think of a neat way to have `A = 11, B = 22`.

Comment: Validationrule is only really suited to simple use cases. inotifydataerrorinfo in the vm is the usual approach for anything substantial. Take a look at fluent validation. Intro example : https://gist.github.com/holymoo/11243164  https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators  Offhand - both properties would probably have the same rule with a predicate checks both are good.

Comment: @Andy, `IDataErrorInfo` is functioning differently: source value is updated and then validation is performed. This approach has major drawbacks compared to `ValidationRule`, because it may lead to inconsistancy if source with invalid value is used elsewhere. `ValidationRule` will prevent this, invalid value stays in the view, everything is good.

Comment: Only relevant if you directly expose a model. Don't directly expose a model. Use viewmodels. Only commit valid data.

Comment: You can possibly use [BindingGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindinggroup), but you will probably have to control `BeginEdit` and `CommitEdit` yourself, never really commiting bad data (the situation `A >= B` should never be commited to the model).

Comment: @Andy, yeah, you are right. I am lazy and often make model suitable for using directly. I should not do this if model is shared, agreed. Was a bad example, still I find concept of validation rule more correct. I just have to overcome this .. ahem.. little problem.

Comment: @Sinatr: "I find concept of validation rule more correct" is wrong. You should implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in your view model if you want to perform this kind of validation. It's not supported by validation rules.

Comment: @firda, BindingGroup looks interesting. It looks very similar to [UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger), where I would do all validations at once when `Ok` button is clicked. Then I will not have above problem. But I want to validate as text is typed.

Comment: @mm8, I just did. And I am not happy. Without `OnPropertyChange(anotherProperty)` it works similarly, means - it does not work. With it - produce same result as with rules, discarding previously typed value if it's for some reasons invalid. E.g. if I'd have 3 properties, `A < B < C`, then  you lost `A` value when updating `B` even before you set focus to `C` which is extremelly user unfriendly: user have to change value `C` first, then `B`, then `C`. Doing it any other way around is not possible. I want user to type wrong `A`, then wrong `B` and when he finally correct `C` - all become valid.

Comment: @Sinatr: There is an `ErrorsChanged` event to be raised whenevery you want to refresh the validation status for a property. Please refer to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) blog post for an example and let us know if you need any further help.

Comment: @mm8, thanks, I'll check `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. My mistake was - I've implemented `IDataErrorInfo`. Sorry.

Comment: A question under the premise, that not valid values being not forwarded to the viewmodel: [A=4(OK) B=9(OK)]  --> A=8(ERR)  --> B=5(OK or ERR?) Which value should be considered for B validation A=4(from view model), then B(OK), or not forwarded A=8 from view, then B(ERR)? For me it looks like validation logic should be in the same layer, where all relevant data are. If you choose to consider a value from VM, then you have red A=8 and black B=5(when you editing B, not A)

Comment: @Rekshino, aye, I was also thinking when to validate `A`: before or after validating `B` (in other words before value of B is accepted and synchronized with source or after). Order matter. And indeed first I have to have all modified values at hand and only then do validation in normal order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ValidationRules` don't support invalidating a property when setting another property.

What you should do is to implement [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.8) in your view model and raise the `ErrorsChanged` event whenever you want to refresh the validation status for a property.

There is an example available in the [this TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx).